# Must declare the scalar variable "@path". (.Net SqlClient Data Provider) in ssm 2017.1

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-restore

Hi I install Microsoft sql server 2016 with management  studio 17.1 and i had database backup from sql 2014, now want restore my backup to new sql server
when click on "..." opposite of device, and open new windows to add
Click on "add" button then get this error
'

> Must declare the scalar variable "@path". (.Net SqlClient Data
>   Provider) '

how can i resolve that

Comment: How are you trying to restore?

Comment: Yes , restore and attach , get the same error.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I don't use any Code only start restore from sql management studio .

Comment: I don't use any Code only start restore from sql management studio . right click on sever > task> restore > with out any more think when click , click on device and then in new windows click on add ==> get above error

Comment: Can you try restore by script?

Comment: in SSMS when you choose RESTORE but before you click OK, find a little button in left upper corner where SCRIPT is written. Script your command in a query window and post it here

Comment: I try restore by script 'USE [master]
GO
restore database Cash FROM disk = 'C:\cash.bak';
Go'     then get this error ==>Msg 3154, Level 16, State 4, Line 3
The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'Cash' database.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in SSMS 17 build 17119.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/3137000

Answer (score 0):

with script i cant do that, in finally i use from import data wizard from remote server to local for solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

[Download the latest SSMS 17.9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) version and try. They have fixed the bug